# I created a simple android app to read the bssid of the currently connected AccessPoint but it always shows me "02:00:00:00:00:00"

Tags: android, bssid

as you can see I already added ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION & ACCESS_WIFI_STATE and I also granted it.

its also in the AndroidManifest, it just wont work..

the code:

```
package com.nx.bssid_a13;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.SupplicantState;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo;
        wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        if (wifiInfo.getSupplicantState() == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) {
            textView.setText(wifiInfo.getBSSID());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now you ask the permission and immediately check the SSID. You need to wait until the user has actually granted the permission in a callback.

Comment: but when I open the app again after closing it, it still shows "02:00:00:00:00:00"

Comment: Are the location services / GPS turned on on the test device?

Comment: yes, always allowed and fine location. I also tested on another phone which runs android 11 and there it works. (my phone has android 13)
I reainstalled it a few times already (my main Phone is a OnePlus 8pro)